# External monitor flashes occassionally only while power cord is plugged-in

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, power-supply, thinkpad, external-display

I have a Thinkpad laptop (E550 to be exact) with an i5 CPU and Intel HD 5500 GPU running with Win 7. Since two weeks, while an external monitor is connected (to the VGA port) **AND** the power cord is plugged in, the (only external) monitor flickers continuously and flashes occasionally (=turns off for about two seconds and then comes back to life), about every 5 minutes.

I was able to isolate the issue by connecting to *(1) a different VGA cable*, and *(2) a different monitor*, which both didn't solve it. However after a few hours of usage without AC power there is not a single problem, and now when I plugged-in the cord again it flickers, flashes, everything.

It should be mentioned that the laptop is relatively new (about 3 months old) and that both an Intel & 3rd-party diagnostic tools didn't find anything wrong with the GPU.

I can't seem to find a solution online, only one forum thread<sup>[--^](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/50943-35-laptop-external-monitor-wall-plug-flicker)</sup> without a solution.

Comment: When you say a different monitor, you had the same problem on a different monitor? Or when you tested with another monitor it worked?

Comment: Finish your task of eliminating the possibilities by trying a different power adapter. This is most likely the problem. If that doesn't fix it then you'll need to swap out the video card. If that still isn't it, the only two likely possibilities are the connectors (power and video) on the back of the laptop or the motherboard (the actual board) itself (neither of which are very easily fixable and both of which already work when running DC).

Comment: @paradd0x A different monitor still has these symptoms.

Comment: @krowe Maybe you're right. Except getting my hands on an identical adapter isn't easy -- but I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran across this (very annoying) issue with the same laptop as well. Luckily, Lenovo has provided a new firmware update for the VGA controller to counter this issue.

Grab it from the attachment here: https://support.lenovo.com/nl/nl/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e550/documents/HT104459?tabName=Solutions

Extract it somewhere and read the provided PDF for further instructions: Follow it to the letter! You really have to extend your desktop to the second monitor for example.

NOTE: While not mentioned in the manual, if your laptop is attached to a OneLink Dock, unplug that before performing the firmware update, you can plug it back in after a reboot.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use the computer now with the patch for a few hours and will update if it really fixes everything.

Comment: I still saw a flicker unfortunately. On the bright side it happens a lot less frequent now though.

Comment: For me everything's alright actually!